# How to use MdiContainer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

This is what I usually do when I want to open a new form from a ToolStripMenu

```
private void alumnoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmAlumno x = new frmAlumno();
        x.ShowDialog();
    }
```

but a teacher told me that it´s wrong because this shouldn´t happen..

[image]

So I guess I have to use MdiContainer but I´m not sure of how to write the code now... Please some help...

Answer (score 3):

If you use MDI, you should call `Show`, not `ShowDialog`. Also you need to set `MdiParent`.

```
Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();

// Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;

// Display the new form.
newMDIChild.Show();
```

[How to: Create MDI Child Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer with a solution to your actual problem instead of describing how to use MdiContainer, since you don't actually need it. :)

Forms have a `ShowInTaskbar` property that defaults to `true`. Set it to `false` and the form will no longer appear in the task bar.

```
private void alumnoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmAlumno x = new frmAlumno();
    x.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    x.ShowDialog();
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) for more information.

Comment: And as a side note, you might be better off just describing the problem you're trying to solve instead of asking how to implement a solution you guess will help you. That way we can provide better answers for you.

Comment: I dunno my psychic powers are suggesting he's working on an MDI exercise. The background form looks like it's supposed to be a MDI parent and the fact that he even knew what MDI is suggests the teacher is looking for a specific solution.

Comment: @Josh I read it as "I'm guessing MDI is what I need because I don't know how to fix it otherwise". Hard to tell which it is for sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Introduction to MDI Forms with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.  Just saying.